# Python + Linux: How to determine cron job is scheduled?

Tags: python, linux, automation, cron

Currently, I’ve scheduled a python script on Linux by adding the following: `*/10 * * * * /file/testscripts/test_script.py` to `crontab -e`.

It did not run after 10 minutes, so I wrote some code to write the current time on there but wasn’t being updated either.

What could be the issue? And how can I determine my python script has been scheduled for a cron job properly?

Thank you in advance and will accept/upvote answer

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Depending on the distro, they could be at `/etc/var/cron.log` or part of `/var/log/kern.log` or somewhere else. Did you use a virtual environment when developing the script?

Comment: @FamousJameous Found `/var/log/kern.log` and opened it via `vi` but nothing is written on there. And, yes the script is placed on a virtual instance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant virtual environment as in [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It is used for making separate python environments on the same machine. What distro is the machine running? Also, could you clarify what you mean by "I wrote some code to write the current time on there"? Where was the code writing to (stdout, a file...)?

Comment: @FamousJameous No worries and apologies on my part for not clarifying. Using `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`. And as for writing the current time, it is onto a simple text file, so `test_file.txt`.

Comment: Ubuntu cron logs are in `/var/log/syslog`. Search for a `CRON` line in that file with a timestamp that matches when you expected the job to run and see what it says.

Comment: @FamousJameous Got it. Found the following logs: `May 15 18:00:01 linuxbox CRON[13824]: (linuxuser) CMD (/usr/bin/python /file/testscripts/test_script.py)`
`May 15 18:00:02 linuxbox CRON[13823]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`
 
`May 15 18:10:02 linuxbox CRON[13885]: (linuxuser) CMD (/usr/bin/python /file/testscripts/test_script.py)`
`May 15 18:10:02 linuxbox CRON[13883]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`

Comment: Your script did run but you don't get any email with the results because you didn't configure the mailing system.

Comment: @Jérôme Believe it didn't run though. The script is supposed to write the time, the time of execution, to a file, but the file didn't get updated with the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty things you could do:

- Try to set full path to python interpreter as well as the script name.
- Pipe stdout/stderr to a log file and print something out: `... test_script.py > /tmp/pythonCron.log 2>&1`
- Is the cron service enabled and running ?

As FamousJameous pointed out, when the cron job was started, you should see some lines in /var/log/syslog:

```
May 15 06:29:00 xyz CRON[9368]: (www-user) CMD (python ...
```

Comment: @MariuceMeyer Isn't `/usr/bin/python` the full path to python interpreter? And could you elaborate on `Pipe stdout/stderr to a log file`? What would I implement on the python script to do so? And how can I check if the cron service is enabled and running? I tried the command: `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` and it showed: `root 1234 1 0 May10 ? **:**:** /usr/sbin/cron -f`. And I did check the syslog and it showed:

Comment: `May 15 18:00:01 linuxbox CRON[13824]: (linuxuser) CMD (/usr/bin/python /file/testscripts/test_script.py) May 15 18:00:02 linuxbox CRON[13823]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`

Comment: Your cron job was running, something was printed out or there was an error.  So you just need to pipe the stdout/stderr into log file (within crontab), as outlined in my answer: `... test_script.py > /tmp/pythonCron.log 2>&1`.

Answer (score -1):

Try with 10 * * * * yourscript name.Then check if crontab -l is include  your script. Then you can check crontab logs.

Comment: Believe `crontab -l` just prints out what is written on `crontab -e` and doesn't necessarily confirm that a cron job has been scheduled properly.